# jQuery / JavaScript sorting div

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have the following code (something like this) and I want to sort the child div of `#item_list` by:

1. **Most recent** (id of child div larger to smaller) * the divs are always follow this order when page is load originally(without adding javascript)
2. **Price high to low** (value in class price larger to smaller)
3. **Price low to high** (value in class price small to big) when the #sort is changed.

```html
sort by:
<select id="sort">
    <option value='1' selected>most recent</option>
    <option value='2'>from highest price</option>
    <option value='3'>from lowest price</option>
</select><br>
<div id="item_list">
    <div id="1000">
        ....
        <span class="price">20</span>
    </div>
    <div id="245">
        ....
        <span class="price">625</span>
    </div>
    <div id="124">
        ....
        <span class="price">77</span>
    </div>
    <div id="55">
        ....
        <span class="price">5</span>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        ....
        <span class="price">31</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to do it, or is there any way I can edit my code to do it?

Comment: You forgot to close the `</div>`. :]

Comment: This seems like an odd use of `id` (plus, it's generally not good practice to use numbers as the first character of an ID, and it can cause issues on older browsers) I'd give them a common class and use a `data-` attribute to store the data you want to sort by.

Comment: how can I sort it after I add a class  and use `data-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

First I collect all the divs under your main container into an array by doing

```
divs=$.makeArray($('#item_list').children())
```

Then I use the selected option number to decide on the suitable sorting criterion (`sorttype`). The array `divs` is sorted according to the given criterion which I apply in the `switch` construct.

As soon as the divs are sorted in the desired way I put them back onto the page (DOM) by appending them to the main container again.

```
$.each(divs,(i,d)=>$('#item_list').append(d))
```

The DOM and jQuery behave such, that a DOM element is never displayed twice. i. e. when I append it to a container, the original instance in that container disappears quietly. At the end of the append action the divs are sorted correctly on your page.

```js
$('#sort').change(function(){
  var sorttype=$(this).val()-1;
  var divs=$.makeArray($('#item_list').children());
  divs.sort(function(a,b){
    switch(sorttype){
     case 0: return b.id-a.id;
     case 1: 
       return $('span',b).text()-$('span',a).text();
     case 2: 
       return $('span',a).text()-$('span',b).text();
    }
  });
  $.each(divs,(i,d)=>$('#item_list').append(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
sort by:
<select id="sort">
    <option value='0'>unsorted</option>
    <option value='1'>most recent</option>
    <option value='2'>from highest price</option>
    <option value='3'>from lowest price</option>
</select><br>
<div id="item_list">
    <div id="1000">
        ....
        <span class="price">20</span>
    </div>
    <div id="245">
        ....
        <span class="price">625</span>
    </div>
    <div id="124">
        ....
        <span class="price">77</span>
    </div>
    <div id="55">
        ....
        <span class="price">5</span>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        ....
        <span class="price">31</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use an object, sort the object and then redraw the div  ?
If you wonder how, I can show you

[edit:here is my proposal, use an array of objects and redraw]

```js
var obj = {};

obj.pointer = document.getElementById("item_list");
obj.list = [
{"name":"orange","price":1.5,"id":1},
{"name":"banane","price":1.2,"id":2},
{"name":"kumkat","price":8.25,"id":3}
];
obj.draw=function(){
 obj.pointer.innerHTML="";
 html="";
 for(var i=0;i<this.list.length;i++){
 html+="<div id='"+this.list[i].id+"'>";
 html+="<span class='name'>"+this.list[i].name+"</span>";
 html+="<span class='price'>"+this.list[i].price+"</span>";
 html+="</div>"
 }
  obj.pointer.innerHTML=html;
}
obj.sort=function(way){
 if(way=='1'){
  this.list.sort(compareId)
 }else if(way=='2'){
  this.list.sort(compareHigherPrice)
 }else if(way=='3'){
  this.list.sort(compareLowerPrice)
 }

}

function compareHigherPrice(a, b) {
  return b.price - a.price;
}

function compareId(a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
}

function compareLowerPrice(a, b) {
  return a.price - b.price;
}

obj.draw();
var select=document.getElementById("sort");
select.addEventListener("change", function(){
 obj.sort(this.value);
 obj.draw();
});
```

```html
sort by:
<select id="sort">
    <option value='1' selected>most recent</option>
    <option value='2'>from highest price</option>
    <option value='3'>from lowest price</option>
</select><br /><br />
<div id="item_list">

</div>
```

Comment: Stop playing with the dom. separate concerns. use arrays and objet and redraw the whole div